# Obtener el valor de retorno del procedimiento almacenado en C #

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo este procedimiento en sql server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CONS_CANASTA_EXISTE]
(
@Id_Canasta nvarchar (255)
)
AS 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_guia_cansta WHERE TxInvPTCanasta = @Id_Canasta)
    RETURN CAST(1 AS bit);
ELSE 
    RETURN CAST(0 AS bit);
```

Que me valida si existe una canasta o no, si existe retorna un 1 si no un 0
desde c# Windows form llamo el procedimiento y le mando el parámetro

**Esta es la capa de acceso a datos donde tengo la conexión y llamo los procedimientos**

```
   public bool CanastasRepetidas(string canasta)
        {
            using (var connection = Conexionsql.AbrirConexion())
            {

                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "SP_CONS_CANASTA_EXISTE";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Canasta", canasta);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

**Esta es la capa de presentación  de donde mando el parámetro**

```
 Query Cons = new Query();
 Cons.CanastasRepetidas(txtBuscarCanasta.Text);
```

No me sale ningún error, mi pregunta es como puedo obtener ese resultado de 1 o 0 para trabajar con el en la capa de presentación y si esta bien o esta mal implementado esto, y si esta mal como se podría hacer o que me hace falta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta agregando un parametro con [`ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.parameterdirection?view=netcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) y ese parametro te almacenara el valor de retorno del SP:

```
public bool CanastasRepetidas(string canasta)
{
    using (var connection = Conexionsql.AbrirConexion())
    {

        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SP_CONS_CANASTA_EXISTE";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // especificas el parametro con direccion de retorno
            SqlParameter returno = new SqlParameter();
            returno.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            
            command.Parameters.Add(returno);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Canasta", canasta);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            
            // obteniendo el valor de retorno
            int valor = retorno.Value;
            
            
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Pero como puedo yo este valor tenerlo en la capa de presentación?

Comment: Retornando el valor que esta en la propiedad `returno.Value` en vez de `true`.